# VBA excel formula from the cell can't be pulled down

Tags: excel, vba

I want to drag formula down to the new row as its created. Unfortunately I can't do it with the code I have:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If ActiveCell.Value = "Re-design " Then

 RowToCopy = ActiveCell.Row
 insertRow = ActiveCell.Row + 1

 Rows(RowToCopy).Copy
 Rows(insertRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

 Dim x As String, y As String, z As String, v As String
 Dim fo1 As String, fo2 As String



 x = "AP" & insertRow & ":" & "DW" & insertRow

  Range(x).ClearContents


  y = "A" & RowToCopy & ":" & "DW" & RowToCopy


  Range(y).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

  z = "A" & insertRow
  v = "A" & RowToCopy


  Range(z).Value = Range(v).Value & "/2"

  fo1 = "AQ" & RowToCopy
  fo2 = "AQ" & insertRow

  Range(fo1).Copy

  Range(fo1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(fo2), Type:=xlFillDefault

  End If

  End Sub
```

[image]

Is there any way to drag the existing formula down to the new row created?

Comment: Key detail from the [`Range.AutoFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill) docs: "The destination must include the source range.".

Comment: But the fo1 is defined as range

Comment: `Range(fo1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(fo1).Resize(2), Type:=xlFillDefault`. The destination must include the source range.

Comment: Or `Destination:=Range(fo1 & ":" & fo2)`